# Code mirror Java mode does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to use Codemirror and it works fine for other modes. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link
      href="theme/ambiance.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="codepane">
function hello(){

}
      </textarea
    >
    <script>
      CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codepane"), {
        mode: "javascript",
        indentWithTabs: true,
        smartIndent: true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        autofocus: true,
        theme: "ambiance",
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my output:

[image]

I am trying to change it to Java mode, but I am not able to find the Java mode in the mode folder
[image]

I know I have to change the mode to  `mode:  "text/x-java",` but it does not work as there is no accompanying mode js file for java. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I had made a mistake in the answer. Please check my edited answer below for a correct configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [Codemirror website](https://codemirror.net/mode/index.html), you can see that when we click on the `Java` mode, it redirects us to [c-like mode](https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/index.html). So, you can use `c-like` mode js file your purpose.

```js
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codepane"), {
  mode: "text/x-java",
  indentWithTabs: true,
  smartIndent: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  autofocus: true,
  theme: "ambiance",
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/theme/ambiance.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.3/mode/clike/clike.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="codepane">
private class InnerClass {
  public int zero() {
    return 0;
  }
}
</textarea>
```

**Note** - There might be some errors as I am not familiar with codemirror, but the above snippet must solve your issue.

**Edit** - You can use `"text/x-java"` as the mode and load the `click.js` as given in the edited snippet to configure proper syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use clike mode,

Refer this linK: https://mycrazycoding.com/React%20doubt/c%20cpp%20java%20editor%20codemirror%20react-js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33046791)